# Any alternative to MONTH() and YEAR() functions which are common to both MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Writing queries (a sql file) that can run both in MySQL and PostgreSQL, everything is OK so far except the following:

```
SELECT MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date) FROM Ticket;
```

for extracting the month number (9,10,11 ..) and year (2011, 2012..) from the Date column (yes thats true, I cannot change the name of this column)  in the Ticket table. It works fine in MySQL but when I run the query in PostgreSQL, it gives the following error message for both MONTH() and YEAR().

```
ERROR:  function month(date) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

After researching a little bit I came along some other functions that will do the job in Postgres, but I am afraid those might not work in MySQL. Strongly looking forward for any possible solution.

Comment: @Hardy Please note that Date is a column in my table ticket...

Comment: I think this answer might be useful for your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4493780/3334049

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well if you use an alias on the front of your field and use ***EXTRACT*** instead, the same query will work for both PostgreSQL and MySQL:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Date) AS MonthOfDate, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Date) AS YearOfDate
FROM Ticket t;
```

[**PostgreSQL SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4177e/2/0)

[**MySQL SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4177e/1/0)

Comment: Huh, I didn't realise MySQL supported the SQL-standard `EXTRACT(...)`. Not that I really use MySQL, but good to know.

Comment: Seeing the `SQL-standard` in previous comment, i wondered about MS-SQL.... It's still not supported in MS-SQL (see: https://modern-sql.com/feature/extract )

Answer (score 0):

Because you are open for any possible solution I have two ideas.

As long as you need to write plain sql statements I would suggest a table prepopulated with dates and their corresponding attributes in columns.

Sometimes I used a table like this:

```
ID   THE_DATE    THE_MONTH_OF_DATE   THE_YEAR_OF_DATE   ...
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    01/01/2014  1                   2014
2    01/02/2014  1                   2014
3    01/03/2014  1                   2014
4    01/04/2014  1                   2014
5    02/01/2014  2                   2014
6    03/01/2014  3                   2014
n    xx/xx/xxxx  x                   xxxx
```

This table prepopulated with the dates that you'll need for your application could be easily joined to all dates and then deliver the column you want.

A better solution would be to use a database abstraction layer/object relational mapper that translates you're queries to the correct database dialect depending on the underlying database, e.g. Hibernate (Java).

Comment: Well, OP didn't mentioned application layer (perhaps it isn't even about that). Also solution with separate date part storing will need additional efforts to maintain data integrity (like `UPDATE` triggers)

Comment: You're right. OP mentioned queries that have to run on different databases, I assumed a application behind that requirement (that's my background).

Comment: I don't understand you're second point: where do problems with data integrity in the prepopulated table appear?

Comment: It's not a problem. It's a thing that should be mentioned, because if data will be mutable, then integrity will fail without additional checks (so triggers as an option, but that again comes to cross-DBMS problem)

Answer (score 0):

there are difference in some functions for both the db, you can see like

mysql - SELECT WEEKDAY('2016-06-24');

Postgres - SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM '2016-06-20'::date);

or for more reference you can visit [postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html)